# Binary substraction : 2's complement & carry

Tags: binary, addition, operation

I want to substract 1 to the number in binary representation 1010 1101. I write the two s complement of 1: 1111 1111, and I sum with the first number:

bitwise addition, with carry, gives 1 1010 1100: because of carry, I end up with 1 bit more. how is this dealt with in binary addition?

also, I am right in the use of two's complement to do addition?

thanks.

Comment: What is the bit width of your computations? If it is a byte you only care about the least 8 bits, so the carry (9th bit) is lost. Two-s complement has sense only with a defined bit width.... (and you are computing modulus 2^8 i.e. 256)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an entirely valid and common way to do subtraction, but the 'carry' flag doesn't mean the same thing that it does for normal addition. Since instead of subtracting `n`, you're adding a large number, the carry flag needs to be handled differently. That extra `1` would usually signify a carry in bitwise addition, whereas here it signifies that everything worked out right. If there wasn't a carry there, it actually means that the result should have been negative - `a - b` was converted to `a + 2^n - b` which was less than `2^n`, meaning that `b > a` and so `a - b < 0`. Either way, it doesn't matter as your result will show up correctly within the 8 bits of your result.